# Displaying local images directly from JSP

Tags: jsp

I am currently trying to display images from a local folder (which I believe is within my app's context) by using

```
<img src="<c:url value='/images/www.jpg'/>"/>
```

I have attempted to use a handful of the other many solutions that exist on the internet inside SO and out to no avail. Under my project directory, I have tried putting the images folder in root, alongside WEB-INF, and inside the root of /src.

Any push in the right direction to be able to display local images from a folder inside the project directory would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<c:url value='/images/www.jpg'/>` will generate an absolute path from the web application root. Therefore, if the said image is really available on the application root, then it should be displayed as usual. What does it render in the generated HTML? Besides, if you accidentally forgot to hard-deploy the application after images had been stored in a new directory, then try hard-deploying the application. Some IDEs like NetBeans require to do this whenever new folders are created in an application until then the directory itself is unavailable in the deployed WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Your path must include something like:

```
<img src="<c:url value='projectname/../images/www.jpg'/>"/>
```

or if you defined as variable all path to images directory, you can use

```
<img src="<c:url value='{projectpath}/images/www.jpg'/>"/>
```

Also you can include this path in classpath variable.